# Multisim is not giving any voltage value for this simple capacitor circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, multisim

This is the circuit:

[image]

Even though I gave 12V it is showing 6V. Maybe it is peak voltage.

Why are the voltages across each capacitor so weird?

Comment: The nodes are undefined because there is no DC path to them, nor a ground.

Comment: then how can I do that. do I just need to use two ground at the end of 2.8uF ,6uF?

Comment: SPICE programs need a ground point somewhere.  Usually at the bottom of V1 but can be anywhere.  
Likely, the way things are now the bottom of V1 will measure -6V.  Need a "0" point somewhere.
Even when that is fixed, Multisim will have a hard time.  This is a very strange circuit.

Comment: The ambiguity to SPICE echoes the ambiguity of the question -- what are the initial conditions? What do you want to measure? If you want to measure the circuit as an impedance divider, you might set initial conditions to zero, and use a PULSE source to ramp from 0 to 12V in a brief time frame. Or you could use an AC source and find the magnitudes in AC steady state.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 0v reference in the circuit. Add a ground reference and put it on the negative side of the battery. This will define where the other side of the probe (imaginary ground side) is connected.